# I need help compiling evince from source package on Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: compiling, 14.10, evince, source-packages

After obtaining build-dependencies and source code for Evince document viewer through

```
sudo apt-get build-dep evince
apt-get source evince
```

on ubuntu 14.10, I run configure script and got the following error:

```
Requested 'gtk+-3.0 >= 3.14.0' but version of GTK+ is 3.12.2
```

Is this bug in the source package, or am I missing something?

Comment: I think your question is incomplete. Are you trying to build the source you downloaded with `apt-get source evince` or are you trying to build source for a newer version of evince you downloaded elsewhere?

Comment: I was just trying to compile the source I got from apt-get source evince, from ubuntu repository.

Comment: It looks like, while Ubuntu 14.10 is based on Gnome 3.12, evince is actually from Gnome 3.14, and so you need newer libgtk to compile it.

Comment: I don't see a patch in debian/patches which changes configure.ac to only require 3.12, so it is odd that you would get such an error. How are you building it exactly? By running configure manually? Or are you using debuild to build a deb package of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu’s source of evince 3.14 is patched to  allow using  gtk 3.12. It's done via the `rtl_avoid_3.14_dep.patch`

Comment: That's right, it was my mistake, since I didn't apply the patches.